# Redirect old domain and pages to equivalent pages on new domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect an old domain to a new domain. The pages have the same names e.g. /my-amazing-page, however on the new website, the url would  be /se/my-amazing-page.

So for example, I need a rule that redirects

```
olddomain.se/recipes/[ALL RECIPE PAGES]
```

to

```
newdomain.com/se/recipes/[ALL RECIPE PAGES]
```

I've tried many of the answers here on Stack Overflow as well as the solutions described [here](https://gist.github.com/ScottPhillips/1721489) but I just can't get any of them to work. All they seem to do is redirect the old domain to the home page (root) of the new domain, and ignore the sub directory and pages.

Currently I am using the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.com/recipes/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newdomain.com/se/recipes/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However as mentioned, this just redirects me to the home page of the new domain. And yes, I have cleared my browser cache and am testing in incognito mode in my browser. 
My current HTaccess file in its entirety:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

# END WordPress

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/recipes/
RewriteRule ^recipes/(.*)$ https://newdomain.com/se/recipes/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Do old domain and new domain in same server?

Comment: @MohammedElhag If I understand you correctly, yes, both old and new domain point to the same server.

Comment: And all the rules above are inside new domain directory right ? i mean this htaccess in main root for both domains or inside new domain directory?

Comment: @MohammedElhag This Htaccess is in the directory for the new domain.

Comment: try to put redirection rules in old one directory , is it possible ?

Comment: @MohammedElhag I don't understand. Both domains, new and old, will point to the same directory on the same server when we put the site live. There would no longer be an old directory. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189197/discussion-between-mohammed-elhag-and-wickywills).

Answer (score 0):

`/recipes` is a url path not host.
 You need to use `℅{REQUEST_URI}` . to match against url path. The following rule should work .

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/recipes/
RewriteRule ^recipes/(.*)$ https://newdomain.com/se/recipes/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The second `RewriteCond` is optional in this rule . You can remove  because the `RewriteRule` already takes care of url path starting with `/recipes` .

Comment: Can't get that to work either unfortunately. I just get redirected to the home page of the new domain

Comment: Try cleaning your browser cache.

Comment: I have. I have also tried in incognito mode, in a new window each time I test.

Comment: Do you any other rules or redirects that execute before this one in htaccess?

Comment: I'm using a standard Wordpress multisite Htaccess, which I have now added to my question so you can see.

Comment: You rules look OK .  Are you using htaccess to handle URLs on your new site?